# How can I tokenize and strize the __func__ macro in C?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I want to *tokenize* and *strize*, with macros, the name of the function we are in, to overload the function (with dlopen()), in C.

I found similar things with `__LINE__` and `__FILE__`, but it seems to be a bit different in the case with `__func__`...

I tried that:

```
#define OVERLOAD2(f) printf("Trying to overload function %s...", #f)
#define OVERLOAD1(f) OVERLOAD2(f)
#define OVERLOAD OVERLOAD1(__func__)

int main() {
    OVERLOAD;
}
```

Compiling with different standards of compilation (c99, gnu11) doesn't change the result; instead of printing:

```
Trying to overload function main...
```

It prints:

```
Trying to overload function __func__...
```

How can I correct those macros?

Comment: What is the `__func__` macro? where did you see it?

Comment: @iharob: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.2.2p1

Comment: What does "strize" mean? Is that even a word?

Comment: @Olaf I know it under the name `stringize`. It's a common macro pair to evaluate a macro and turn the value into a string.

Comment: @a3f: less `z`, more `s`, but yes, that one is known, of course. I just wonder: typo or twitteritis? At least the title line should really have no obvious typos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what the C11 draft says about `__func__`:

> **1**   The identifier __func__ shall be implicitly declared by the
>   translator as if, immediately following the opening brace of each
>   function definition, the declaration
>
> `static const char __func__[] = "function-name";`

As you see `__func__`, unlike `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`, is no preprocessor macro, so you can't evaluate it during the preprocessing stage.

**But** in your code, you don't even need to do that. Just change

```
#define OVERLOAD2(f) printf("Trying to overload function %s...", #f)
```

to

```
#define OVERLOAD printf("Trying to overload function %s...", __func__)
```

as you can see in the standard's description of `__func__`, it's already a string. No need to stringize it.

---

If you need the function name as a "bare word" at compile time, e.g. an implicit `#define __FUNC__ myfunc`, you're out of luck.

It's not possible in standard C. GCC additionally provides __FUNCTION__, but despite its all-caps name, the GCC manual says:

> Neither of them is a macro; the preprocessor does not know the name of
>   the current function.

MSVC provides `__FUNCTION__` as a macro but it's defined to a string and you can't strip away the double quotes.

Only way around that is writing your own preprocessor or rethink your approach

Comment: Thanks, that's ok to stringize this, but how can tokenize it? I want to do things like `__func__##_foo`, to call another function prefixed by the current function's name.

Comment: @Tsigorf You can't. I extended my answer.